# Unable to telnet to 127.0.0.1 (local Linux VM) to test SMTP port 25

Tags: kali-linux, smtp, telnet, sendmail

I have the latest Kali Linux running on Hyper-V as a VM:

- Sendmail is installed (testing email server)
- Domain name purchased, say AlphaMoon.org with MX record pointing to my ISP IP address
- Netstat confirms port 25 is listening, and router is port forwarding SMTP on 25 to Kali VM
- I am able to send a test email using Sendmail to the localhost
- MXtoolbox is showing the MX records pointing to my ISP, but fails testing SMTP

I am unable to telnet to 127.0.0.1:

[image]

Firewall (UFI.services has a closed state)

I am trying to test telnet on 25 to make sure I can send emails externally but keep getting a refusal error. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: What does 127.0.0.1 have to do with the rest of your question? Do you know *where* 127.0.0.1 is?

Comment: Testing local connection on 127.0.0.1 should be able to tell me if it is accepting connectings to itself, in my case telnet on 25, but get refused. I think this is why MXtoolbox is failing to test SMTP to my Kali mail server. With me?

Comment: So you have a machine on a VM somewhere in the cloud, MXtoolbox is failing to test SMTP, so what you are attempting to do is login to this VM and test port 25 via telnet on the VM itself?

Comment: No my VM is on a Hyper-V on a physcial laptop of my own. I have access to the VM itself,  and able to ping it's FQDM. Since sendmail is able to send and recieve emails locally from and to itself (my account), when testing externally it seems to fail. Possibly blocked on the VM? I am unable to telnet to itself on 25. How can I confirm if telnet is accepting connections on a Kali VM?

Comment: "I am able to send a test email using Sendmail to the localhost". Then you should be able to do that with `telnet` as well. Run `wireshark` on `lo` and see what happens when you successfully test it, then imitate with `telnet`. As you didn't tell how you tested it, that's as detailed as I can go. Possibly `sendmail` is only listening on an external IP, but my crystal ball is not able to do remote debugging over Q&A's.

Comment: What happens if you telnet to the local IP of your server rather then 127.0.0.1? Its possible that sendmail is simply not listening on localhost (or, somewhat less likely firewalled)

Comment: This is the wireshark result on lo:

 1 0.000000000    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 74 39688 → 25 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65495 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2629299965 TSecr=0 WS=128
    2 0.000003800    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 54 25 → 39688 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
    3 27.578795500    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 74 49622 → 23 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65495 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2629327544 TSecr=0 WS=128
    4 27.578799800    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 54 23 → 49622 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0

Comment: telnet to actual internal IP also same result of refusal. So the above wireshark result was from a "telnet 127.0.0.1 25" attempt